# Changing the verbosity of rosout.log file

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, roscpp, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been digging further into the log files under `~.ros/log` and am interested in changing the verbosity of what appears there. As an example, a driver node for an Ensenso camera is generating output like this in the main `rosout.log` file:

```
1550159090.698210207 ERROR [/home/jlangsfeld/Workspaces/mcc_deboning/src/ensenso_ros_driver/ensenso_camera/src/camera.cpp:221(open) [topics: /rosout, /tf, /ensenso_front/raw/left/image/compressedDepth, /ensenso_front/raw/left/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/raw/left/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/raw/left/image/compressed, /ensenso_front/raw/left/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/raw/left/image/compressed/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/raw/left/image, /ensenso_front/raw/left/image/theora, /ensenso_front/raw/left/image/theora/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/raw/left/image/theora/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/raw/left/camera_info, /ensenso_front/raw/right/image/compressedDepth, /ensenso_front/raw/right/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/raw/right/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/raw/right/image/compressed, /ensenso_front/raw/right/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/raw/right/image/compressed/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/raw/right/image, /ensenso_front/raw/right/image/theora, /ensenso_front/raw/right/image/theora/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/raw/right/image/theora/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/raw/right/camera_info, /ensenso_front/rectified/left/image/compressedDepth, /ensenso_front/rectified/left/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/rectified/left/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/rectified/left/image/compressed, /ensenso_front/rectified/left/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/rectified/left/image/compressed/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/rectified/left/image, /ensenso_front/rectified/left/image/theora, /ensenso_front/rectified/left/image/theora/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/rectified/left/image/theora/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/rectified/left/camera_info, /ensenso_front/rectified/right/image/compressedDepth, /ensenso_front/rectified/right/image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/rectified/right/image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/rectified/right/image/compressed, /ensenso_front/rectified/right/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/rectified/right/image/compressed/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/rectified/right/image, /ensenso_front/rectified/right/image/theora, /ensenso_front/rectified/right/image/theora/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/rectified/right/image/theora/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/rectified/right/camera_info, /ensenso_front/disparity_map/compressedDepth, /ensenso_front/disparity_map/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/disparity_map/compressedDepth/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/disparity_map/compressed, /ensenso_front/disparity_map/compressed/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/disparity_map/compressed/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/disparity_map, /ensenso_front/disparity_map/theora, /ensenso_front/disparity_map/theora/parameter_descriptions, /ensenso_front/disparity_map/theora/parameter_updates, /ensenso_front/cloud, /diagnostics] The camera '182089' could not be found
```

As you can, this is just an unnecessary wall of noise. How can I change the format to exclude the topics list and possibly the line number as well? The environment variable mentioned [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Console_Output_Formatting) only changes what appears on stderr in the terminal and doesn't affect the file.

Note also that I'm running this node from a launch file without `output="screen"` but I'm still getting this output only in `rosout.log` and not in the node's log file. In fact nothing appears in the node's log file except a single `INFO` statement. Is this expected?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315656/changing-the-verbosity-of-rosout.log-file/) by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 971 on 2019-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2019-02-14**:
I think not. I remember looking into this in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some more searching, I discovered this issue has already been addressed for melodic. The global parameter `/rosout_disable_topics_generation` can be used to make the topic lists empty. Or, the `/rosout/omit_topics` parameter will prevent the list from appearing in `rosout.log` at all.

Relevant PRs:

- https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1241
- https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1234

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2019-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2019-02-15**:
I'll add this to "reasons to upgrade Ubuntu"